# get value from html page with conditions

Tags: php, html

I need help in php:

Imagine visiting the link "http://example.com/gen" and every time I visit the result in html on the page is different:

```
code=0001
refresh the page ...
code=1545
refresh the page ...
code=7845
....
```

I want to know how can I get the following code to the = sign to use in most places of the page

Comment: sounds like you want to defeat a CAPTCHA

Comment: Use `file_get_contents` to get the contents of the page, Simple PHP DOM Parser to parse it, and then extract the code from the appropriate element.

Comment: You should post more details on exactly what you want to parse. Is the body of the HTTP response literally only `"code=0001"`, or is there HTML markup? Can you post an example of the page you need to parse?

Comment: `preg_match('~code=(\d+)~',$content,$match);$code=$match[1];`

Comment: Basically `$rand=mt_rand(1000, 9999); echo "code=" .$rand;` that will generate a 4-digit random number. (*Quick & Dirty*)

Comment: <?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/gen');
preg_match('~code=(\d+)~',$content,$match);
$code = $match[1];
echo $code;
?>

nothing show :(

Comment: I can show you something that will generate a 4-digit code which will also start by a `0` if you want. @DGAP it shows a 4-digit "random" number. It's random numbers you want to get, right?

Comment: the page is external, cannot modify. only need content after code=THIS NUMBER

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I visit example.com/gen and the html source only this "code=xxxx"

I need only get "xxxx"

Comment: What is `example.com/gen` - "your" website or someone else's website?

Answer (score 0):

Makes an array of 10 codes from the URL:

```
<?php

$codes = array();

for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++){
  $string = file_get_contents("URLHERE");
  $string = explode('=',$string);
  $code = $string[1];
  $codes[] = $code;
}

?>
```

Usage Usage:

```
foreach($codes as $code)
 echo $code . "<br />";

echo "First Code: {codes[0]}";
?>
```